# PHP "Call to undefined function strtolower"

Tags: php

We have code that uses standard function `strtolower`.

However from time to time, randomly, we got following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function strtolower() in /path/xxxx.php:20
Stack trace:
#0 /path/xxxx.php(63): ffff()
#1 {main} thrown in /path/xxxx.php on line 20
```

As long as I can check `strtolower` is standard function and it does not depend on anything and should be always available?

## update:

I can not disclose the code, but is something like this:

```
function browser_check(){
    foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $data){
        $data = strtolower($data);

         // check for SQL injections and other hacks
    }
}

browser_check();
```

There are no includes or namespaces. We "prepend" this file using php.ini to be executed before any other code on our website.

I will check what happen if I prepend in a file with namespace.

Who knows, it might be PHP bug :)

## update why question should be reopen

The question is not standard question "why my function does not work".
This is either a PHP bug or server config bug.

If I was able, I would give more information about the problem, but currently there is not enough info.

We are trying to understand it from two weeks now without success.

## update

For the moment I am leaving it like this. I am not sure, if I do `file_put_contents`, if it will work at all.

```
    try{
        $data = strtolower($data);
    }catch(Exception $e){
    }
```

## update

try / catch obviously did not helped here.

Currently I left it as:

```
    if (function_exists('strtolower')){
        $data = strtolower($data);
    }
```

Meanwhile, I checked the file with HEX editor. Spaces are real spaces 0x20.

I also began to log POST / GET data and I can see that at least sometimes, there are no $_REQUEST to be processed, e.g. `foreach` loop does not execute code inside, so the problem is somewhere in the PHP linter.

Friend was able to see lots of results in google about similar problems, however no result is very useful. Search is "Call to undefined function: strtolower".

## update

We continue to get errors even if code is like this:

```
            if (function_exists('strtolower')){
                    $data = strtolower($data);
            }
```

Then we changed like this and error appeared again:

```
            try{
                    $data = \strtolower($data);
            }catch(\Error $e){
            }
```

Comment: Could you show us the piece of code from which this error comes from? Is it inside any namespace?

Comment: Let's highlight: ***time to time, randomly***. If the same code sometimes works and sometimes doesn't, on the same PHP installation, that has nothing to do with namespaces…

Comment: If it was a namespace issue, shouldn't the error rather be: `undefined function SomeNamespace\strtolower`? Also, you shouldn't need to add backslashes to core functions. Let the OP show us the code before we start guessing.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204739/discussion-on-question-by-nick-php-call-to-undefined-function-strtolower).

Comment: why are you using the server to check the client? o.O and what do you mean prepend this file using php.ini? Surely, you should be using a bootstrap file that does this action before the site load? o.O

Comment: @trey I expect they use https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file. Can't say it's a particularly great idea, especially the "check for SQL injections" stuff… but let's leave that aside for the purpose of this question.

Comment: @deceze huh, that just feels weird, but I guess that's a matter of preference, was trying to suggest an alt. way but it seems like this is a somewhat valid method (in theory) at least. I guess is pos the file isn't loading php properly before doing the execution of php :S

Comment: Tried prepending before file with namespace, works OK. Since it throw an exception, I can use try / catch and log. but what exactly to log?

Comment: Does it happen only with `strtolower` or are other functions also affected?

Comment: What is your PHP version? Is it PHP 7.4.1?

Comment: PHP version is 7.3.2

Comment: I still don't think the question is worth reopening. I can't see how anyone would be able to give a factual answer based on the limited amount of information we have.

Comment: how random is random too? Once every few weeks? Once a day? Is there a process to running the script? Is there a certain trigger you've noticed before seeing the error?

Comment: This sounds exactly like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23660848/unexplained-syntax-error-with-logical-or/23663971#23663971 - `$data = strtolower` after the equal sign isn't a space (check the bytes of the php file). That would at least generate exactly the same error message `PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function  strtolower() in /tmp/x.php:3`. In any event it's unlikely to be random, just that the pattern hasn't been recognised/stated.

Comment: @AD7six is not non break-able space. Just checked with HEX editor.

Comment: @Dharman - 3-4 times per day

Comment: @Nick if it's happening 3 or 4 times a day, it's the code _when that happens_ that will (maybe) indicate the problem. Things like this usually boil down to "the code being executed is not the code being debugged", you need to find/identify the pattern - good luck :)

Comment: i think is library issue, but will update once ome more time pass

Comment: Updated with the answer

Comment: Happened to me too at PHP version 5.6.38. Randomly. Around 4-5 times per day. Still no cure

Comment: try reboot the whole server if you can. we did not had this chance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was some problem with dynamic linking.

I suppose some package of the system (like libc.so) was updated and then weird behavior began.

All I did is full stop Apache and start it again.

Comment: I had a similar issue: strtolower worked, but sometimes it breaked the umlauts. Only sometimes. 

After a restart of Apache it was solved.
(Apache 2.4.25 under Windows)